# excel copy and paste in Windows Search

Tags: windows, excel, vba, search

I am using Excel 2010 and Windows 7 Pro. I want to copy one cell content into Windows Search box. How do I write a VBA for that?

```
Sub CopytoSearchWindow() 
'CopytoSearchWindow Macro ' ' 
sCell = Range(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8)).Value
```

Comment: writing code would be a good start.

Comment: This is what I have so far:

Comment: Sub CopytoSearchWindow()
'
' CopytoSearchWindow Macro
'

'
    sCell = Range(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8)).Value

Comment: That's it?  (NB: I updated your question to include the code. In the future, please update your **questions** -- code does not render properly in the comments)

Comment: Thank you for doing that. As far as my code, I don't know how to call the Windows Search box. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: can we enquire why you want to do this? There are better ways to search, if that is the reason.

Comment: We're trying not to have the user retype it in the Windows Search box since it's already in the excel spreadsheet. The text in the excel spreadsheet is part of a pdf filename that needs to be found during a search in Windows.

Comment: see my answer - a bit of hacky send keys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Shell.Application object to do this in conjunction with sending some key strokes.

Example: (replace my searchString bit with whatever you like)

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub searchExample()

    Dim searchCell As Range
    Dim shellApp As Object
    Dim wshShell As Object

    On Error Resume Next 'to catch if user presses cancel
    Set searchCell = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8)
    On Error Goto 0

    If searchCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set shellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    shellApp.FindFiles
    Sleep 500
    wshShell.SendKeys searchCell.Value & "{enter}"

End Sub
```

Shell.Application reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Windows scripting host Shell reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to VBA. How do I incorporate that with my code that ask the user to select which cell to copy?

Comment: edited - should be plug and play now. On StackOverflow, Answers are demonstrative - it is expected you may have to show a modicum of thought or effort to implement an answer. But really - if you don't know enough VBA to replace a variable for another then I would suggest learning the fundamentals of VBA before trying to provide something to a client/colleague as it is asking for trouble otherwise. There are many simple guides out there on the internet. Anyway, I hope it helps.