# Use Windows Search to find a lengthy list of files

Tags: windows-search

I am searching for a relatively large collection (2000+) of files within a group of specific folders.  The specific folder (and subsequent sub-folders) are indexed locations.  I know the names and paths of all of the files. They are listed in an excel spreadsheet.

I wish to display them all in one saved search.

I am able to compile a search using [AQS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx): `name: filename1 OR name: filename2 .......OR name: filenameN AND Word`. This code works well for a few file names. However, I have a list of about 2000 files.  And copy and paste into the search window does not seem to work with such a large collection of search criteria.

I did try doing the paste with [VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372662/excel-copy-and-paste-in-windows-search). But I think my query is too large.

Also, because I have so many search criteria, I suspect compiling a [.ms-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221681/how-can-i-programmatically-use-windows-file-explorer-to-perform-a-search/30221777#30221777) file from scratch will not be practical.

My question is: Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this? Possibly something combining a series of excel formulas with the CMD Prompt.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested.

I solved my problem using [VB script](https://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd).  Instead of creating a saved search file, I will manually create a folder and "import" the links to it:

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sLinkFile = "C:\MyShortcut.LNK"
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)
    oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyProgram.EXE"
oLink.Save
```

I used Excel formulas to concatenate the script and my known paths.  Copy and paste to a .vbs file.